# How to check if I arrived at a page from same page vs. another page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a Java Web App. One of the pages contains a form with 3 checkboxes and a table.
Depending on which checkboxes are checked, different info gets populated in the table.
There is no submit button. The form is submitted whenever the user checks or unchecks one of the boxes.

Theoretically, I want the user to be able to uncheck all the boxes, which will result in the table being empty. However, if the user arrives at the page from another page, or upon initial visit to the app, I want them to have one of the boxes checked by default, and the respective data displayed in the table.

Comment: Can't you just set one of the checkboxes to checked?

Comment: I could, but the problem with that is: what if the user unchecks the one I set to checked by default, and checks the other two. The expected behavior then would be for the form to be submitted, the page reloaded, and the new checked buttons to remain checked. But since I set one to checked by default, the changes made in the form by the user, would not be preserved when the view is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could differentiate the request to the same page (submission) from the requests comming from other pages (or direct url access) by the HTTP method.

Make your form use a POST method and check if the request method is GET (direct access or link from another page) or POST (form submission).

Comment: Note that this will also correctly handle the case that the user visits your page and then reloads it, whereas the other answers currently given, do not.

Comment: However, the distinction is not bulletproof. Anyone is allowed to perform a POST request to your page (not only your page itself). But in this case, you will treat it as a form submit (and hopefully authorize and validate the request) so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Better pass 3 different request parameters based on your 3 checkboxes to your JSP/Servlet and depending on the parameters modify the table accordingly.

if user is coming from another page, at the start of the doGet or doPost, set your request parameter to a default value.

Comment: that is pretty much the scheme I followed, with a small variation, that the checkboxes are actually all named the same for convenience of processing... but I guess my real question was _how do I determine_ if the request came from another page or from the same page - because after all, both types go through the same servlet before the view is displayed.

Answer (score -1):

you can use sessions to help determine where you a user is coming from. Before a page redirects to another page have the orignal page set some session attribute. Somewhere at the top of the page you can check the user's session attribute to see where they are coming from

i.e.

Page 1

`session.putValue("referringPage", "Page1");`

Page 2

```
if (session.getValue("referringPage") != "Page2") {  
         //do something
}
```

Edit:

Better method might just be to check the header using something like

`request.getHeader("Referer"));`